# Appending <li> to <ul> Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, dynamic, html-lists, append

I have 2 collapsable div's with list's in both of them. Each list is supposed to display JSON information dynamically. I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" id="set">
        <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" id="trip1">
            <h3>Trip 1</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="info1">
                <li>Name 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" id="trip2">
            <h3>Trip 2</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="info2">
                <li>Name 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the following script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#trips').collapsible();
    });
    $.getJSON('http://141.219.205.44:8080/json/trip/list', function(data) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
             $('#info1 ul').append('<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>').listview('refresh');
        }

</script>
```

I know it retrieves the JSON data just fine, I just can't get it to append to the !

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? If so please mark it as the answer to help others find answers to similar questions in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#info1 ul')` does not exist it is trying to find an element named #info1 with an ul inside it remove the ul and it will append to the `ul#info1`.

How does the data object looks like? are you sure you have that many items in your data (0-1)?

add the getJSON also around your dom-ready method to be sure that the DOM has loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $('#trips').collapsible();
    $.getJSON('http://141.219.205.44:8080/json/trip/list', function(data) {
        for ( var i = 0;l=data.length; i < l; i++) {
            $('#info1').append('<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>').listview('refresh');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: [{"class":"json.Trip","id":1,"city":"Houghton","endDate":"2012-11-12T05:00:00Z","name":"Austin","notes":"Notes","purpose":"Purpose","startDate":"2012-11-12T05:00:00Z"},{"class":"json.Trip","id":2,"city":"Hancock","endDate":"2012-11-13T05:00:00Z","name":"Nelson","notes":"I have some notes","purpose":"To get to the other side","startDate":"2012-11-13T05:00:00Z"}]

Comment: either stackoverflow addes a strange character or there is something wrong with your quot character on the name but it seems that there is a strange character on your "name" variable (copy it to a text editor I get `.... ?"name":"Austin",....` on your code (look at the error log on your browser with: jsfiddle.net/GSaDZ/) if I change the code http://jsfiddle.net/GSaDZ/1/ then it works.

Comment: I got it. Was just a syntax error with a "}"

'<script>
    $.getJSON('http://141.219.206.161:8080/json/trip/list', function(data) {
     for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            $('#info1').append('<li>' + data[i].name + '</li>').listview('refresh');
       }
    });
</script>'

Comment: the visible problem was your selector, good it worked out for you.